# how to develop onenote plugs-in in windows desktop client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-interop, office-addins, onenote, clonenode

I want to develop some plug-in for onenote client in windows. I had found there is a new technology "Office Add-ins" to develop office plug-in, which use javascript, web technology and Microsoft Graph. However, It seems not support onenote client in windows, only support onenote web ([Host and platform availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability)). **So, to develop plug-in for onenote client, should I use old technology like VBA or VSTO? Are there some way to develop plug more easily and quickly?**

Besids, is there any doc for office VSTO? And what technology would you advise me to use.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't support creating OneNote add-ins. The best what you could do is to implement the [IDTExtensibility2 Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/extensibility.idtextensibility2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) on your own. `IDTExtensibility2` contains methods that act as events when the interface is implemented. Visual Studio calls these methods whenever an event that affects an add-in occurs, such as when it is loaded or unloaded, whenever a change is made to it, and so forth.

See [OneNote add-ins documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/onenote/) for more information on web add-ins.